# Why is dropdown moved to the left in IE 11 but not in Chrome or FF?

Tags: css, django-admin, internet-explorer-11

I have created a dropdown menu that works great in Chrome and Firefox but when trying it in IE 11 the dropdown content ends up on the side.

I've googled and search but cannot find a solution.

note that it should go into a Django Administration page header and that's why there are a few !important. It also means that the dropdown should be on top of all other elements on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:left;float:left;"><a href="kalle.html">Test</a></h1>
<style type="text/css">
    .dropbtn {
    background-color: #417690;
    color: #f5dd5d !important;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

    .droplink {
    background-color: #417690;
    color: #f5dd5d !important;
    padding: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdowncontainer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}


.dropdown {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black !important;
    padding: 6px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1; 
    color: black; 
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #376880;
}
.droplink:hover {
    background-color: #376880;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdowncontainer">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn" href="">XXX</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="installations.html">Installations</a>
            <a href="files.html">Files</a>
            <a href="task.html">Tasks</a>
            <a href="release.html">Releases</a>
            <a href="copy.html">Copy</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <a class="droplink" href="node.html">Nodes</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've created a JSFiddle with the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cLbfmaLn/)

Comment: I believe this is because the `left`, `top` properties are not set and it's taking either random (IE) or the browser given ones?

Comment: looks fine to me in both Edge and Internet Explorer :-/

Comment: By modifying the left, top properties of .dropdown-content I was able to move the positioning of the dropdown menu.. How can I automatically get the bottom, left values of .dropbtn?

Comment: @Caelan. I notice that the JSFiddle works great in IE11 but the full code example I pasted in the question does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving `position: relative` to `.dropdown` class.

The behaviour of `position: absolute` elements when no explicit `position: relative` element has been specified varies from browser to browser. Hence, the anomaly.

Also add `top: 0` & `left: 0` to `.dropdown-content`

```
.dropdown-content {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Tried setting the position: relative to .dropdown class. This renders the dropdown box behind the other elements on the page. I'm starting to think that I need to redesign the dropdown menu rather than trying to fix this.

Comment: You need to provide `top: 0` and `left: 0` values also. The structure seems fine.

Comment: I added top, left to .dropdown-content and set .dropdowncontainer position: aboslute; That way It will arrange correctly on left while I'll have to manually specify the top value which works, but would prefer if I could get the top value automatically. Thanks for helping me get this far. Noticed that setting .dropdowncontainer to position: absolute hides it behind other elements on certain pages.  I think I'll be satisfied by manually setting top, left attributes on .dropdown-content

Comment: As I said the default behaviour for `top` varies across different browsers. So, manual is safe in this case. And, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Try set for .dropdown-content left and top values.

Comment: I've tried that and that works. But how can I now automatically get the bottom left values of .dropbtn so it will align properly?

Comment: You need create parent container with property: position: relative, and you dropdown should set position in him.

Comment: If I add a parent div with position: relative the dropdown is rendered behind other objects but correctly in relation to top and left. Extremely frustrating.

Comment: Maybe add this parent container property z-index: 999; and add z-index for dropdown container too?